# Changing android:updatePeriodMillis programmatically

Tags: android, android-appwidget, appwidgetprovider

OK, so I have done some research and the consensus seems to be that you can't update `android:updatePeriodMillis` programatically.

It seems that you have to use `AlarmManager` instead, which seems like using a sledghammer to crack a nut... odd that the API doesn't just let you update the core `updatePeriodMillis`.

There's always a slight risk with relying on what's out there on the web, since APIs tend to develop and old answers are no longer relevant.

So I'm just checking that this is still the case.  For example, the guide at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html at least hints that it *is* possible to change the update period of the `AppWidgetProvider`.  When discussing `updatePeriodMillis` it says:

> "You might also allow the user to adjust the frequency in a configuration—some people might want a stock ticker to update every 15 minutes, or maybe only four times a day."

And *then* goes on to talk about using `AlarmManager` but apparently only in relation to avoiding waking the device rather than to changing the update period.

Thanks for any help on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So I'm just checking that this is still the case.

Yes, it is still the case that you cannot update `updatePeriodMillis`. Which is too bad, as I'd love to see an `updateUpdatePeriodMillis()` method. Particularly if this were done via some sort of builder or transaction object, implying that it too might be changed via an `updateUpdateUpdatePeriodMillis()` method.

:-)

> It seems that you have to use AlarmManager instead

You could use `JobScheduler` on Android 5.0+ as well, though I suspect that you won't like that much either.

You could also allow the user to configure some multiple of `updatePeriodMillis`, then only do your work every N updates, though this isn't terribly efficient.

Or, you could not update your app widget periodically at all, instead updating it only as needed based on app functionality, rather than based on time. IMHO, this is what most apps should be doing.

Comment: Hmm, OK thanks.  It's odd that Google acknowledge in their own guide that the developer might well contemplate allowing the user to update the interval, and yet don't provide a method to do this!  You have to abandon the core method and adopt a completely different solution, or apply an ugly kludge.  Shouldn't be so difficult to do something so simple.  Only doing some work every N updates seems like a reasonable way to go.  Will look into AlarmManager anyway.

Comment: I'm starting to understand, why setting small value for updatePeriodMillis in the manifest and then skipping some updates is, at leastin some cases, much worse than using Alarm Manager or Job Sheduling... In the first case your widget will be redrawn on each update, e.g. list with data will be requeried... In the approach with an independent alarm/job you may actually do nothing and spend close to zero resources if not needed!